# Should we make a small prize for the millionth question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was just thinking that because this is a math site and numbers are just a bit important to math that maybe the person who asks the $1$,$000$,$000$th question or even the $800$,$000$th (or whatever interval we could decide on) could be given a small reward, such as a rep bonus, nothing huge, just as a kind of reward? Maybe we could require it to be a well-recieved question as well, so people wouldn't just spam random questions in order to get themselves the rep bonus (although I doubt anyone would do that.)

Comment: On Meta, downvotes typically indicate disagreement rather than judgments on the quality of the question.

Comment: Could people comment/answer why they disagree instead of just downvoting? I would love to have some feedback, no hard feelings.

Comment: There is also problem how to define milionth question. Since posts are commonly deleted and undeleted, it might happen several times that the number of posts on the site is the same. And the question which is 1000000-th oldest question (among not-deleted questions) is very likely to change quite often.

Comment: You might be interested in the post [History of Math.StackExchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/history-of-math-stackexchange), which would be a suitable place to record such an event.

Answer (score 9):

**No, we shouldn't do this because there doesn't seem to be any good reason to.**

What would be the purpose of such a thing? It would be given out roughly randomly, which seemingly defeats the point of reputation which is to measure the quality of a user's contributions. Can you give a reason why this would be a good thing to do? Generally speaking, changes to existing systems should be done for a reason, not just for fun. I could understand a site-wide thing for the occasion of 1 million questions, such as "double reputation week" but I don't see any good reason to reward whoever happens to ask the millionth question, and it seems like a potentially divisive act.

Comment: This was exactly something I was looking for. I understand how my idea may not have been the best, but something like a double rep work would be great in my opinion. I just wanted to celebrate something big like a million questions, wasn't completely sure how.